# When user drop pin on Map, Delegate method "didSelectAnnotationView" automatically called

Tags: ios6

I am developing an App in iOS6. I am using the Apple's Map. In which i have to the drop pin on Map where user taps. I am doing this by using UITapGestureRecognizer on Map. But problem is that when user tap to drop the pin then Map Delegate method "didSelectAnnotationView" also called automatically after pin dropped. I have also tried by using UILongPressGestureRecognizer but same result. This is not happening with Google Maps means in iOS 5. In iOS 5 it is working fine. I am doing research on that but unable to get any result. Please can you tell me that:

Is there any way to handle this. OR Apple Map provides the feature to drop pin dynamically itself.

Thanks.

Following code i have written:

```
- (IBAction)singleTapGestureOccur:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
CGPoint touchPoint = [sender locationInView:_mapView_View];
CLLocationCoordinate2D cord = [_mapView_View convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:_mapView_View];
MapAnnotation *annotation = [[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithCordinate:cord];
[_mapView_View addAnnotation:annotation];
```

}

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view{
NSLog(@"DidSelectAnnotation");
```

}

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{
if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
    if ([[touch.view class] isSubclassOfClass:[MKPinAnnotationView class]]) {
        return NO;
    }else {
        return YES;
    }
}else {
    return YES;
}
```

}

Comment: Show the code you are using to add the annotation on tap.  Also, do you have any code in didAddAnnotationViews?  If so, what does it do?

Comment: i have written following code:

Comment: I have not implement didAddAnnotationViews.

Comment: The code shown should not cause didSelectAnnotationView to fire.  The problem is somewhere else.  Is selectAnnotation being called from anywhere?

Comment: I have not written any code except this. This code is running in iOS5 perfect but creating this problem in iOS 6. I don't know why. i am worried about that.